# PHP stream_socket_client and SSL

Tags: php, ssl

When I use `tcp://64.41.200.100:80` it works fine, but with
`ssl` it failing to read response, here is my source example

https://gist.github.com/undercloud/d246473370aec7f19c2e42414ae00693

P.S. I need this way to transfer data, I know about `file_get_contents`,`fopen`, but I still need low-level data I\O

P.S.S Hmm... Maybe need ssl certificates settings? How to create this .pem file and how to setup options?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76420 The error message means, that the remote party you try to connect to only supports the outdated TLSv1.1. Ideally this should be fixed on that end, if at all possible.

Comment: Welcome on SO. It seems you are using TLS v1 and the version are not compatible. Check your OpenSSL version, if you can use an recent TLS version.

Comment: ok big thanks! I tried requests to different hosts via https and from different devices, I will try to update the OPENSSL library in LINUX and write the results

Comment: ... and please tell me more about ssl - should I generate my own certificate in order to send requests? or is it not required and everything should work by default?

Comment: So... I install PHP 7.3 with OpenSSL v1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019, but nothing has changed and the error remains the same

Comment: Problem in `stream_get_contents`, you must use `fgets`,`fgetc`,`stream_socket_recvfrom` to read data, but now i get encrypted data looks like `>bÂev��h����$��q*�zhP#`, how to get normal data string?